# Count rows with bigger average

Tags: mysql, sorting, average

Each student has some scores (and each score has `student_id` column).

I want to calculate student average, compare his average with other student, and find his position in his class.

Is it possible to find his position based on his average with 1 query? (may contains subqueries or joins)

I can sort all students by their average by this query:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM
  scores s LEFT JOIN lessons lesson
  ON lesson.id = s.lesson_id
WHERE lesson.display = 1
GROUP BY s.student_id
ORDER BY AVG(s.score) DESC
```

but it needs processing with PHP `array_search` function. (I think using MySQL functions is better, in this situation)

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_id, AVG(scores) as 'average' from lessons as l, scores as s 
where lessons.id = s.lesson_id and lesson.display = 1 
GROUP BY s.student_id order by average desc`
```

Try this query

sample http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fb8d/1

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but it sort students by their average. I've got it before... (read my question again), I want to find 1 student position. (whose hist id is `100`, for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
    select s.id, AVG(l.scores) as average from lessons as l, student as s 
    where l.id = s.lessonid and l.display = 1 
    GROUP BY s.id order by average desc
```

can solve your problem
Check this [**link**](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?263260-MySQL-Get-position-of-sorted-rows#11)

Thanks to Meherzad's sql query

Comment: Thanks, but I want to find student position. Not the student who is the third one in his class. (at the end of your query, you have `WHERE rank = 3`)

Comment: I added `rank=3` for your convenience that you can even search within their ranks....Else you print complete table....

Comment: Yes, but I don't need complete table or the third student. I want student number 100 position in his class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT average)
FROM (
  SELECT AVG(score) as average
  FROM scores INNER JOIN lessons
       ON scores.lesson_id = lessons.id
  WHERE display=1
  GROUP BY student_id
  ) sub_scores
WHERE average >= (SELECT AVG(score)
                  FROM scores INNER JOIN lessons
                       ON scores.lesson_id = lessons.id
                  WHERE display=1
                        AND student_id=1)
```

In the subquery `sub_scores` I'm calculating all averages of all students, in the outer query I'm calculating the number of distinct averages bigger than the average of student 1.

This will return the position of student 1.

Depending on what you are after, you might want to remove DISTINCT clause.

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33e16/3).

Comment: @kikio isn't it correct? I'm returning the position of a given student... it's not clear if you are looking for this, or if you need to rank students (like in Bohemian's answer)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a user defined variable over the result set.

Try this:

```
SELECT *, (@rank := if(@rank is null, 1, @rank + 1)) as rank
FROM (SELECT s.*
  FROM scores s 
  LEFT JOIN lessons lesson ON lesson.id = s.lesson_id
  WHERE lesson.display = 1
  GROUP BY s.student_id 
  ORDER BY AVG(s.score) DESC
) x
```

Comment: x is the required alias for the nested query (it can be anything, but it must be something. I found the syntax error - I forgot that  mysql is sensitive to the position of `*` in the `SELECT` list: it must be first. I have edited the query and it should work now